How to get dynamic content from website with C#
I'm looking to obtain informations automatically from a website via a C# application. The problem is that these informations are dynamic. I can't retrieve them from the page's source code. Even with F12 on my browser, I find a way to indentify these informations!
I've tried to obtain them using the Nuget Selenium package, but I can't get the information I want. I can't use the body content because all the informations are dynamic, and I haven't found a Select that works because the page doesn't have specifics id.
Here are two examples:
https://web.idle-mmo.com/wiki/items?page=1&sort_by=id_asc
On this page, I'd like to get the name of each object and the link to its page, as well as be able to “click” on the button to display page 2, because the direct link to page 2 leads to page 1.
https://web.idle-mmo.com/wiki/items/mystic-sword/ZjlPA8v9NMaXNEyMe2Oa?same_window=true
Here I'd like to retrieve informations on the latest sales as well as the price history for the last few days (mouseover the graphic).
In both cases, I can't figure out how to retrieve what I need.
I've tried quite a few things but nothing worked, so here's the embryonic code that retrieves the source code but doesn't work in my case.
 private void TestReadPage()
 {
      IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://web.idle-mmo.com/wiki/items/mystic-sword/ZjlPA8v9NMaXNEyMe2Oa?same_window=true");

      // Getting the body but useless
      var body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Text;

      // No result trying to get last sold but just the list, not the average sold price in the graphic
      var lastsold = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("!border-t-0"));

        driver.Quit();
 }


Using selenium you can try to find element by xpath. this code allow to wait until element present.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.xpath("YOUR_XPATH_HERE")));


That's the problem, I don't find an path for the elements I am looking.

try to use
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]")));
`
and then you can access elements you looking for.
Next line of code (after wait.Until) will be run when the dynamic content is loaded.
